# What happen to $use property in controller for CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I find it very strange that the removal of the `$use` property on controllers is not mentioned at all in the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html) for CakePHP 3.

In the section for [controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#id2) it doesn't refer to it at all.

Can anyone explain what happen `$use`, why it was removed and what can I do to migrate my CakePHP 2 controllers to 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was replaced by using `$this->loadModel()` in your actions or inside the `initialize()` method of your controller.

The reason for removing it is that we are trying to go away from declarative properties, as they are difficult to test and work with in general. Also, we prefer people using the associations system instead of using the tables directly from the controller.

Comment: What is this associations system? I don't see it mentioned in the cake book. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: For example `$this->Posts->Comments` or `$this->Posts->Tags` in your controller